# Can I expose two methods in my Server with NServiceBus?

Tags: wcf, nservicebus

I was looking an answer for this but I couln't find it. As you know, the NServiceBus library came with a sample that's call WCF Integration. It has an interface that the Server exposes as a WCF service, right? This interface has only one method inside. My idea is to have more than one method inside that interface, is this possible? 
I have my own project, in which I have my interface with more than one method and my idea is that this WCF Service to have a method similar to "Process" from the sample, that publish messages.

Code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICancelOrderService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceOf_CancelOrder_ErrorCodes/Process", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceOf_CancelOrder_ErrorCodes/ProcessResponse")]
    ErrorCodes Process(CancelOrder request);

    [OperationContract]
    ErrorCodes HelloWorld(CancelOrder request);
}

public class CancelOrderService : WcfService<CancelOrder, ErrorCodes>{}
```

I trie to inherit from ICancelOrderService, but didn't work.

So, any suggestions? Thanks people...

Regards, Matias.

---

thanks for your soon response. Maybe my explanation wasn't clear enough. I have my Server that inherits from WcfService, but my idea is to have more than one OperationContract, one similar to Process, and the others ones commons Wcf OperationContract, that they won't interact with NSB.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICancelOrderService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceOf_CancelOrder_ErrorCodes/Process", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IWcfServiceOf_CancelOrder_ErrorCodes/ProcessResponse")]
    ErrorCodes Process(CancelOrder request);

    [OperationContract]
    void HelloWorld(int var);
}
```

My code will be something like that. With your response I realize that the code of the first post was wrong.

So, is this possible, or I have to look other way to implement this?

Thanks, Matias

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered account. You can now edit this question, leave comments under answers and (eventually) accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

The WCF service that is exposed is only to get messages onto the bus.  Once the messages is on the bus it will be dispatched to the appropriate message handler.  You can then Publish from your handler.  NSB will expose methods for each message handler that inherits the WcfService<T,K> class.  Just keep using that class to expose more methods.